# Alternar parte de um texto para negrito sob uma condição

Tags: angularjs, html5

Preciso de ajuda para mudar a cor de uma parte específica de um texto. É o seguinte, tenho uma string que quebrei em várias frases separadas para pegar as frases relevantes. As frases são do formato de tupla (frase, relevância). Quero então concatenar a string novamente porém, no html, mudar a cor das partes que tem relevância 'sim'. É possível fazer isso dentro de uma mesma div? Estou usando AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as diretivas [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) ou [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) para aplicar classes e estilos condicionalmente a um elemento HTML.

Para o seu problema, se eu entendi corretamente, utilizando a diretiva `ng-class` a solução seria algo do tipo:

```
<div ng-repeat="frase in vm.frases">
  <span ng-class="{'my-bold-class': frase.relevante === true}">
    <!-- A classe my-bold-class será aplicada somente e somente se frase.relevante for verdadeiro  -->
    <!-- Independente da do valor de frase.relevante, a mensagem definida em frase.texto será exibida -->
    {{frase.texto}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Sendo a variavel `frases` definida como:

```
frases = [
  {
    texto: 'Esta é uma mensagem importante',
    relevante: true 
  },{
    texto: 'Esta não é uma mensagem importante',
    relevante: false
  }
]
```

Você pode verificar o resultado neste [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/MEHaYITAW7TcbTk2mGbl?p=preview).

Seria algo assim que você gostaria?

Comment: Isso mesmo, @sshann. Vou aplicar no meu código. Grato!